# C++11 Unrestricted Union Copy Constructor

Tags: c++11, union, copy-constructor

I would like to be able to use an unrestricted union as a simple value type, so I need a copy constructor. What is a safe way to make a copy constructor for an unrestricted union, i.e.:

```
union MyUnion
{
    int m_int;
    std::string m_str;

    MyUnion() :
    m_int(0)
    {

    }

    MyUnion(const MyUnion & _other)
    {
        //?????
    }

    ~MyUnion()
    {

    }
};
```

Is there any safe/easy way of implementing this? It appears to me that there is no safe way of making a copy without knowing if the _other union is either an integer or a string. Am I missing something?

Comment: I think the problem is, that in order to make a safe copy, it needs to be ensured that the std::string copy constructor will be called (as it manages its own memory internally). So I don't think std::copy/memcpy etc will do the job?

Comment: You need to keep track of the currently active member. "Unrestricted" doesn't mean "magic"; you still have to do the legwork.

Comment: okay thank you, that's what I thought. thanks for confirming!